# Как записать в vector "потомок" базового класса?(Работа с классами С++)

Tags: c++, классы, указатели, наследование

Есть базовый класс Figure. И я хочу создать vector в котором будут хранится объекты других классов Circle Square Triangle(эти классы как бы потомки). Как это сделать правильно?

Пока что идея такая, но если записать еще один объект класса Circle у первого объекта изменятся данные на данные второго объекта(данными являются параметры):

```
vector<Figure*> fig;
Circle circ;
for(int i=0; i<2;i++)
{
    cin>>circ;
    fig.push_back(&circ);
}
```

Класс Сircle:

```
class Circle :public Figure
{
public:
    Circle() :Figure() {}; 

    Circle(const Circle& circ) :Figure(circ) {};

    Circle(int size) :Figure(size) {};
...
...
}
```

Comment: Покажите как вы создаете и записываете второй объект? И еще покажите реализацию Circle

Comment: @AlexanderChernin ну в общих чертах как-то так

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно это?

```
for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
{
    Circle * circ = new Circle;
    cin >> *circ;
    fig.push_back(circ);
}
```

Только по окончании работы освободите все указатели в векторе.

По окончанию работы, перед тем, как вектор выйдет из области видимости или будет удален как-то иначе -

```
for(auto p: fig) delete p;
```

После этого можно для надежности очистить вектор -

```
fig.clear();
```

Comment: `for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
{
    Circle * circ = new Circle;
    cin >> *circ;
    fig.push_back(circ);
    delete circ;
}`

Получается я могу чистить память только так?

Comment: @etoya тогда в векторе у вас будут указатели на убитые объекты, что приведёт к нехорошим последствиям

Comment: @AlexanderChernin вот это меня и волнует, просто как тогда мне почистить мою память? При таком решении я не вижу другого способа

Comment: @etoya и даже такой способ череват утечками. Нужен умный указатель

Comment: См. дополнение к ответу.

Comment: Но выделенная память под circ все равно не освобождается, [upd]хотя мб я ошибаюсь

Comment: @etoya circ -автоматическая память. А значение указателя было перенесено в вектор, будет удалено в цикле, но в ручную. Но... если push_back сломался с исключением, то не будет. тогда не следует делать из вектора нудисткий пляж для указателей Ж)

Comment: Поверьте, что так вся память освобождается.

Answer (score 2):

Приведенный в вопросе код вообще не создает нового объекта. Он просто сохраняет адрес локального объекта в автоматической памяти в копиях указателя, хранимых в векторе. При выходе из этого блока кода указатели в векторе станут недействительными.

Унаследованные объекты надо  создавать динамически а не автоматически. Иначе указатель  становится некорректным. 
Код вроде

```
for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
{
    Circle * circ = new Circle;
    cin >> *circ;
    fig.push_back(circ);
}
```

легален, но опасен тем, что можно забыть очистить память. Это может оказать архитектурной проблемой. Когда вектор перестанет существовать? Можно ли отследить все ветки исполнения?  Более того, в С++ выполнение может быть прервано исключением и разверткой стека и соответсвующий удаляющий код может остаться неисполененым. Непосредственная проблему в самом цикле можно решить так:

```
for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
{
    Circle * circ = new Circle;
    cin >> *circ;
    try {
       fig.push_back(circ);
    } catch(...)
    {
      delete circ; 
      // сделать что-то еще важное, у нас нет памяти для перевыделения вектора. 
    }
}
```

Этот код параноидален и тяжело читаем, но в некоторых случаях без него не обойтись. Для вектора из трех объектов обычно ничего  такого не требуется, но в реальной ситуации ...

Концепция RAII предполагает, что контейнер должен уметь высвободить память при уничтожении, значит он должен хранить что-то , что владее выделенной памятью. Т.е. "умный" указатель. С их использованием тоже можно достичь полиморфизма и ковариантности контейнеров.

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class A {};
class B : public A {};

typedef  std::shared_ptr<A> PtrА;
typedef  std::shared_ptr<B> PtrB;

std::vector<PtrА> v;

int main()
{
   v.emplace_back(std::make_shared<B>());   
}
```

Одна проблема, `std::vector<PtrА>` и `std::vector<PtrB>` -неэквивалентные типы, придется приводить в "ручную"

Нам понадобится либо

```
using  SharedFigurePtr = std::shared_ptr<Figure>;
typedef SharedFigureRef = std::weak_ptr<Figure>;
```

либо,

```
typedef UniqueFigurePtr = std::unique_ptr<Figure>;
```

в зависимости, нужно ли  разделение владения. Следующие контейнеры владеют динамически  созданными объектами. Как только вектор будет уничтожен,  указатели уничтожат указуемые объекты. `figShared` может делить владение с другими  объектами, т.к. SharedFigurePtr обладает счетчиком использования.

```
std::vector<SharedFigurePtr> figShared;
std::vector<UniqueFigurePtr> figUnique;
```

Нужно учесть, что `unique_ptr` не копируем, он перемещаем!

```
figShared.emplace_back(std::make_shared<Circle>(/*Аргументы?*/));
figUnique.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Circle>(/*Аргументы?*/));
```

`make_unique` введен в С++14, для С++11 придется использовать  создание  объекта

```
figUnique.emplace_back(std::unique_ptr<Circle>(new Circle()));
```

Этот метод в отличии от `push_back` может вернуть ссылку на соданный объект-указатель, что очень удобно в том случае когда нам нужно немедленно получить к ему доступ.

Такая сложная обертка нужна для исключения утечки. `emplace_back` может вызвать исключение, если передать результат выражения new напрямую, то оно будет потеряно! Но так передается умный указатель, при исключении созданный объект будет уничтожен.

Чтобы получить указатель на Circle, следует использовать `dynamic_cast<Circle*>(figUnique.back().get())`. С уникальными указателями приходися поступать так.

Теперь, как корректно скопировать объект-указатель с разделением владения? Для обычных указателей у нас есть `dynamic_cast` и `static_cast`, но он "порвет" связь копии указателя с оригиналом. Для *умных указателей* есть *специальные* шаблоны `std::dynamic_pointer_cast` и `std::static_pointer_cast`, приводящие к *умному* указателю нужного типа с сохранением связи.